# Foundation Variables Undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, zurb-foundation

I'm a little embarrassed I can't seem to figure this out.  I'm getting an error whenever I refer to a foundation variable in my `scss` sheets, for example.

> Undefined variable: "$primary-color". (in /my/path/to/mysheet.scss)

Here's my `app.scss`

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree ./a_folder
*/
@import "foundation/foundation-global";
@import "foundation/_settings";
@import "foundation";
```

I suspected it's because the `import`s are after the `require`s.  But when I reverse the order, all my stylesheets are missing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I met same situation in Bootstrap. If using `require`, all variables can't be used on custom scss files.

The solution is to use `@import` but no `require` at all.

I suggest you to remove all `require`, and `@import` your custom css files manually in `application.css.scss`. `@import` will also work for asset pipeline, so nothing to worry at all, just type some words more.

Comment: There's got to be a better solution than trading Rails require functionality for importing each and every file.

Comment: @TimScott, I've researched this before. To my knowledge, No. And I don't think this is anything worse than `require tree`. CSS @import is native CSS. Also, import or require CSS manually is MUCH BETTER than `require tree` because it's hard to control the order of requiring and the order is very important to CSS. Even using `require`, I don't use `tree` but require each file manually.